# How to extend SerializerMetaclass from DRF and apply it to my serializer?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, metaclass

Using Python 3.6

In Django Rest framework:

```
@six.add_metaclass(SerializerMetaclass)
class Serializer(BaseSerializer):
...
class ModelSerializer(Serializer):
```

I want to extend the `SerializerMetaclass`:

```
class JSONDataMetaclass(SerializerMetaclass):
    """Meta class to dynamically add SerializerMethodField and look up JSON data"""
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        for field in getattr(attrs.get('Meta'), 'json_fields', []):
            def closure(field):
                def _(self, obj):
                    if len(field) == 1:
                        return obj.raw_data.get(field[0])
                    return obj.raw_data.get(field[1])
                return _

            attrs[field[0]] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
            attrs['get_{}'.format(field[0])] = closure(field)
        return super(JSONDataMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

So that my serializer can use my metaclass

In my customer serializer:

```
@six.add_metaclass(JSONDataMetaclass)
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

But this has caused some strange behaviors, eg. it doesn't respect the `depth` defined and serialize all the way down to nested relationships.
What am I doing it wrong?